# How to make a src.rpm unpack the source to whatever directory I want?

Tags: rhel, rpm

I'm trying to make an rpm that will unpack the source to a custom directory, such as /asdf.  When I run it, it always errors out saying "cannot create %sourcedir /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES".  Is there something I can put in my .spec file that will make it unpack the source (which is just a .tar.gz file inside the src.rpm) to a custom directory when I do the command "rpm -i xyz.src.rpm"?

Comment: I found the answer.  http://www.logiqwest.com/TechnicalPapers/rpmScriptInstall.html provides step-by-step instructions for doing what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as simple as calling tar in the spec file and then specifying the path I wanted to untar to.

Comment: If it was all about making the spec file with what you intended (than a command line option) then use install section in the spec file to just untar the file to a specific directory.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I did.  I just didn't understand how the spec file worked in terms of rpmbuild.

Answer (score 4):

use [rpm2cpio](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-miscellania-rpm2cpio.html) to unpack rpm. Or use [alien](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/alien/) to convert the rpm to other packages (deb, tar...)

The exact syntax for using rpm2cio

```
rpm2cpio ./package_name-test-1.1-1.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

Comment: Does not answer the question, how to unpack a source package.

Comment: @DustWolf This is valid for .src.rpm files too

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use `-r or --root option` of rpm to specify an alternative root path as the top directory.

You also can extract the files from rpm with rpm2cpio command. man rpm2cpio.

Comment: Use that option on what?